When normal extensions are normal
I am wondering if the following statement is correct for each of the following properties $\mathcal P:$ normal, separable, and Galois or not:
If $K \subseteq L \subseteq M$ are fields and $M/K$ has the property $\mathcal P.$ Then $L/K$ has property $\mathcal P$
An algebraic extension $E/F$ is normal if it is algebraic and the minimal polynomial of every element of $E$ splits in $E[X].$
An algebraic extension $E/F$ is separable if every element of $E$ is separable over $F$ (a polynomial f is separable if it has only simple roots.)
A Galois is a finite, normal and separable.
I am guessing that since separability is transitive, then this is correct. But since normality is not this is incorrect.
Am I correct or I am missing something? What is a counterexample for normality?

Your title is... weird?

Also... you say "$E/F$ is separable if every element is separable", and then parenthetically say what it means for a polynomial to be separable. So presumably the prior sentence should have been "is separable if the minimal polynomial of every element of $E$ over $F$ is separable."

Why did you tag this question [tag:finite-fields]?

Note that transitivity isn't really what matters here. For example, the property "the degree of the extension is finite and even" is transitive: if $K\subseteq L\subseteq M$, and both $[L:K]$ and $[M:L]$ are even, then so is $[M:K]$. But from $[M:K]$ even you cannot conclude $[L:K]$ is even.

Neither normal nor "finite and Galois" have property $\mathcal{P}$. (Note that there is such a thing as an infinite Galois extension...)
Note: I misread the problem initially. What is below is an example to the question asked. Since I got a couple of upvotes before the mistake was pointed out, I am keeping the original examples, below the horizontal line
For a counterexample to "if $M/K$ has the property then so does $L/K$" for both "normal" and "finite Galois extensions":
Take $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of unity. Then $M$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $K$, so it is normal and Galois. But $x^3-2$ has a root in $L$ and does not split over $L$, so it is not normal (and hence not Galois) over $K$.
It is part of the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory that if $M/K$ is Galois, then $L/K$ is normal (and hence Galois) if and only if $\mathrm{Aut}_L(M)$ is normal in $\mathrm{Aut}_K(M)$. Here the latter is $S_3$ and the former is a subgroup of order $2$.

I originally misread the problem as asking whether $L/K$ and $M/L$ having the property implies $M/K$ having the property. This is false for "normal" and "finite and Galois", and the example below shows this.
Recall that extensions of degree $2$ are always normal; and in characteristic zero, they are always Galois. They are normal because if $[F:K]=2$ and $a\in F$, then the monic irreducible of $a$ over $K$ has degree at most $2$ and at least one root, hence splits.
So let $K=\mathbb{Q}$, and $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, and $M=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$.
Then $L$ is normal over $K$, as it is of degree $2$. And $M$ is normal over $L$, because it is of degree $2$ (it is obtained by adding a root of the polynomial $x^2-\sqrt{2}$). But $M$ is not normal over $K$, because the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $K$ is $x^4-2$, and it only has two roots in $K$, not the required four. Note that both $L/K$ is finite and Galois, and $M/L$ is finite and Galois as well, though $M/K$ is not Galois.

Both statements are true for separable extensions. An extension $L/K$ is separable if the minimal irreducible over $K$ of every $a\in L$ is separable. If $M/K$ is separable, then this also holds for all $a\in L$, so $L/K$ is separable. And if $M/L$ and $L/K$ are separable, then so is $M/K$, which can be shown using multiplicativity of the separability degree.

There is a typo I think in the first line you are saying $L$ is normal over $K$ but in the second line you are saying it is not.

I guess you are not giving an example that suits my question. In my question I am asking if $L/K$ has property $\mathcal P$

@Emptymind Oh, misread it. But that is still false. I'll fix it.

@Emptymind fixed (as well as the typo).
